# Finding area of bottle with calculus

Tags: calculus

So i am finding the area of my 600ml mount franklin waterbottle with calculus. I have done all my calculations in cm.

I have used a section of the bottle which is a cubic function with the formula;

-0.25711x^3 + 0.5766x^2 + 0.1744x + 2.7

This to find the area under the curve for the bottle needs to be integrated with this formula

pi * intergral (upper limit and lower limit) of the equation squared.

Giving:
$$\int^{10.6}_{8.6}\left(0.0630512x^6 - 0.289569x^5 + 0.244884x^4 - 1.15482x^3 + 3.14406x^2 + 0.96176x + 7.29\right)dx$$

I have provided a web link to the formula, however it does not include pi.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=d56e8a800745244232d295d3eae74aae&title=Area%20under%20the%20Curve%20Calculator&theme=blue&i0=-0.0630512x%5E6%20-%200.289569x%5E5%20%2B%200.244884x%5E4%20-%201.15482x%5E3%20%2B%203.14406x%5E2%20%2B%200.96176x%20%2B%207.29&i1=8.6&i2=10.6&podSelect=&includepodid=Input&includepodid=VisualRepresentationOfTheIntegral&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1

I get this answer 61738.9 * pi
                 = 193958.47
This is unreal as the volume can only be 600ml am i doing something wrong? Please i need assitance!

Comment: What are the units of your limits of integration?

Comment: I didn't know calculus now comes in bottles.

Comment: They are in cm mate

Comment: How did you manage to find this cubic? I plotted it and it is negative over your entire region of integration, and looks nothing like the edge of water bottle I've ever seen. You have also not correctly squared your function - the leading coefficient _must_ be positive!

Comment: I used 4 points which are; (0,2.7) (0.5,2.9), (1,3.2), (1.9,3.4) and what is the function supposed to be when squared? Im using my calculator incorrectly i assume.

Comment: Why aren't you integrating from 0 to 1.9 then, if that's the range that's meaningful?

Comment: Should all instances of the word "area" in the question be "volume" instead?

Answer (score -1):

just some tips that might help:

Your formula above won't give you the answer. If you want to integrate to find the area, then you need to do some imagination. Imagine your bottle is cut so that you can express its 3d geometry in a 2d plane. If you can find a formula for this line, then simply integrate it and you have the area of the bottle.

You will probably need the widest section's circumference of the bottle as your bounds. So you would have [0,circumference] as your bounds.

You will probably also need the circumference of the thinner section of the bottle, but more so to determine the equation of your line.

I hope this gives you a better idea on what the solution may look like. Goodluck!